# LWC Select component how to default value in JS not HTMl

Tags: developer, lwc-dom, lightning-web-components, lwc-oss

I am trying to default the value of the select to a specific value based on a condition so I cannot just put selected in the html. I need JS code that will automatically update it. For this though I just need to know how to default the value in JS not html for female

Here is the html:

```
<template>
 

<div class="nds-col nds-size_12-of-12 nds-medium-size_12-of-12 nds-large-size_12-of-12">
  <div class="nds-col nds-size_12-of-12">
     <div class="nds-form-element nds-form-container"> 
        <div class="nds-form-element__control nds-form-element__control-animated-label">
           <div class="nds-select_container">
            <select class="nds-select nds-has-value" name="genderfield" required onchange={handleChange}>
            <option value="male">Male</option>
            <option value="female">Female</option>
            </select>
            <label class="nds-form-element__label" for="select-01">Gender</label>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Here is my js right now but it isnt working:

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';
import omniscriptSelect from "vlocity_ins/omniscriptSelect";
import template from './selectOverrideGenderOption2.html';
import pubsub from 'vlocity_ins/pubsub';
import { OmniscriptBaseMixin } from 'vlocity_ins/omniscriptBaseMixin';

export default class SelectOverrideGenderOption2 extends OmniscriptBaseMixin(omniscriptSelect) {
    
    /**
     * This method is overriden as part of example for clearing the value if we delete the data from the field and the field is Required
     * The OOTB behaviour - This is intentionally done, we are keeping last successfully entered value to avoid loss of data
     * @param {*} evt 
     */
     connectedCallback() {
        setTimeout(() =>
          this.template.querySelector('[name="genderfield"]').selectedIndex = 1
        );
      }

    handleChange(evt) {
        
        
        if(evt.target.value === "") {
            
            this.applyCallResp(evt.target.value);
            Promise.resolve().then(() => { 
                this.setElementValue(null, false, true);
                this.dispatchOmniEventUtil(this, this.createAggregateNode(), 'omniaggregate');
            });
        } else {
           
            this.applyCallResp(evt.target.value);
        }
    }   

    render() {
        
        return template;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default HTMLSelectElement doesn't use "value" to set a value, it uses `selectedIndex`.

Also, during connectedCallback, the template hasn't yet been rendered. Add an asynchronous callback, and you should be fine:

```
setTimeout(() =>
  this.template.querySelector(someCssSelector).selectedIndex = 1
);
```

In addition, you cannot reliably use Id values in LWC, so set the name attribute instead:

```
<div class="nds-select_container">
    <select class="nds-select nds-has-value" name="genderfield" required onchange={handleChange}>
    <option value="male">Male</option>
    <option value="female">Female</option>
    </select>
    <label class="nds-form-element__label" for="select-01">Gender</label>
</div>
```

---

```
  connectedCallback() {
    setTimeout(() =>
      this.template.querySelector('[name="genderfield"]').selectedIndex = 1
    );
  }
```

[Demo Code](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/TBimbO75Sjcpj9G2sXJT/src/app.js)

Comment: I put it in the render and it worked, Thank you very much!